# PDE Characteristic Equations - Remembering Them?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there a quick smart intuitive way to see that

$$\frac{dx}{F_p} = \frac{dy}{F_q} = \frac{du}{pF_p+qF_q} = - \frac{dp}{F_x+pF_u} = - \frac{dp}{F_y+qF_u}$$

are the characteristic equations for a non-linear pde $F(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)= 0$?

Doesn't even matter how illogical or inapplicable so long as it gives the right result. If I forget them, it'd just take absolutely *ages* to re-derive them in an exam.

Comment: The book *Physics for mathematicians* by Michael Spivak has a nice derivation of the characteristic equations to a first-order PDE. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not that intuitive or even easy to remember, but you may want to have a look at the most general case of the *Lagrange-Charpit equations*:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x_i}{F_{p_i}}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}p_i}{F_{x_i}+F_u \, p_i}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sum_i \, p_iF_{p_i}}, $$ which are the characteristic equations for the non-linear pde:

$$ F(x_1,x_2, \ldots, p_1,p_2,\ldots, u) = 0, $$

where $p_i = u_{x_i}$ and $x_i$ are the set of indepent variables, whilst $u$ is the unknown.

Cheers!

([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case))

Comment: I picked the two-variable case for simplicity but if you have a nice intuitive way of remembering the form of those equations I'm all for it.

Comment: Hi there again, @bolbteppa. I'm afraid I have no other more intuitive way to recall these equations. The ones above are those which I usually remember when I need them for a particular 2D or 3D case.